# Adding a loading bar to WKWebView and selecting its color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am trying to add a loading bar to the  top of my WebView page. Where would I add the code. Also is it possible to change the color of this loading bar?[image]

```
    class CycleViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0196, green: 0.4, blue: 0.2902, alpha: 1.0)

        webView.isOpaque = false
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://jwelsh19.wixsite.com/countryday")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any workarounds for how to add loading bar as I didn't see any code which is related to Loading bar here.

Comment: Add your custom bar and set accordingly the webview progress bar

Comment: @ShauketSheikh How do you add a custom bar to WKWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you dont want an custom view then you can user SFSafariViewController to achieve this. use below code

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://jwelsh19.wixsite.com/countryday") {
    let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
    config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true

    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

if you dont want to user SFSafariViewController then add uiprogress bar to your webview containerview and observe webview progress and update UIProgressbar accordingly
And for observing webview progress use webview progress observer

```
    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
            progressView.progress = Float(webView.estimatedProgress)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do need a custom view... is it possible to add UIProgresBar to WKWebView?

Comment: yes it is possible
you can refer this link for UIProgressBar in wkwebview
https://gist.github.com/fxm90/50d6c73d07c4d9755981b9bb4c5ab931